# while those who are not employees - How can I make sure it does not make mistakes at executeQuery?

Tags: java

It is such that "employee" should be able to see all orders in the database. while those who are not employees must be able to view their own order based on their userId.

The problem is just that my executeQuery makes mistakes.

Error say:

> variable p might not have been initialized

For example, if I give my `PreparedStatement p = null`, it tells me that the first SQL is "**NullPointerException**"

```
ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>(); // tom collection.

    try {
        Connection cc = Connector.connection();
        String SQL;
        PreparedStatement p;
        if("employee".equals(user.getRole()))
        {
            SQL = "SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY orderId DESC";
        }
        else
        {
            SQL = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE userId = ? ORDER BY orderId DESC";
            p = cc.prepareStatement(SQL);
            p.setInt(1, user.getId());
        }



        try(ResultSet rs = p.executeQuery();)
        {
            while(rs.next())
            {

                orders.add(new Order(
                            rs.getInt("orderId"), 
                            user, 
                            rs.getInt("length"), 
                            rs.getInt("width"), 
                            rs.getInt("height"), 
                            rs.getDate("date"), 
                            rs.getDate("shippingDate"), 
                            rs.getBoolean("shipped")));
            }
        }

        return orders;
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex){
        throw new Other(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

It is such that I have a constructor who has these values.

```
public Order(int orderid, User user, int length, int width, int height, Date dt, Date shippingDate, boolean shipped) {
    this.OrderId = orderid;
    this.user = user;
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.dt = dt;
    this.shippingDate = shippingDate;
    this.shipped = shipped;
}
```

As a starting point, I only use `OrderID`, `length`, `width`, `height`, `date` and `shippingDate` and `shipped`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `PrepareStatement p` in your `if` block as well (like you do in the `else`). Like,

```
PreparedStatement p;
if("employee".equals(user.getRole())) {
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY orderId DESC";
    // Add this...
    p = cc.prepareStatement(SQL);
} else {
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE userId = ? ORDER BY orderId DESC";
    // Just like here
    p = cc.prepareStatement(SQL);
    p.setInt(1, user.getId());
}
```